# R - building new variables from sequenced data

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, sequence

This is an update / follow-up on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55639062/detecting-sequence-by-group-and-compute-new-variable-for-the-subset) question. The answer outlined their doesn't meet the new requirements.

I am looking for an efficient way (`data.table`?) to construct two new measures for each `ID`.

Measure 1 and Measure 2 needs to meet the following conditions:

Condition 1:
Find a sequence of three rows for which:

- the first `count > 0`
- the second `count >1' and
- the third `count ==1`.

Condition 2 for Measure 1:

- takes the value of the elements in `product` of the third row of the sequence that are:
- in the `product` of second row of sequence and
- NOT in the `stock` of the first row in sequence.

Condition 2 for measure 2:

- takes the value of the elements in `product` of the last row of the sequence that are:
- NOT in the `product` of second row of sequence
- NOT in the `stock` of the first row in sequence.

Data:

```
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
              seqs = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,1,2,3,4),
              count = c(2,1,3,1,1,2,3,1,2,1,3,1,4,1),
              product = c("A", "B", "C", "A,C,E", "A,B", "A,B,C", "D", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A,B,C", "D", "D"),
              stock = c("A", "A,B", "A,B,C", "A,B,C,E", "A,B,C,E", "A,B,C,E", "A,B,C,D,E", "A", "A,B", "A,B", "A", "A,B,C", "A,B,C,D", "A,B,C,D"))

> df2
   ID seqs count product     stock
1   1    1     2       A         A
2   1    2     1       B       A,B
3   1    3     3       C     A,B,C
4   1    4     1   A,C,E   A,B,C,E
5   1    5     1     A,B   A,B,C,E
6   1    6     2   A,B,C   A,B,C,E
7   1    7     3       D A,B,C,D,E
8   2    1     1       A         A
9   2    2     2       B       A,B
10  2    3     1       A       A,B
11  3    1     3       A         A
12  3    2     1   A,B,C     A,B,C
13  3    3     4       D   A,B,C,D
14  3    4     1       D   A,B,C,D
```

The desired output looks like this:

```
   ID seq1 seq2 seq3 measure1   measure2
1:  1    2    3    4   C         E 
2:  2    1    2    3    
3:  3    2    3    4   D
```

How would you code this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things you need to know to be able to do this:

- `shift` function to compare values in your groups
- `separate_rows` function to split your strings to get to the normalised data view.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                  seqs = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,1,2,3,4),
                  count = c(2,1,3,1,1,2,3,1,2,1,3,1,4,1),
                  product = c("A", "B", "C", "A,C,E", "A,B", "A,B,C", "D", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A,B,C", "D", "D"),
                  stock = c("A", "A,B", "A,B,C", "A,B,C,E", "A,B,C,E", "A,B,C,E", "A,B,C,D,E", "A", "A,B", "A,B", "A", "A,B,C", "A,B,C,D", "A,B,C,D"))

dt[, count.2 := shift(count, type = "lead")]
dt[, count.3 := shift(count, n = 2, type = "lead")]

dt[, product.2 := shift(product, type = "lead")]
dt[, product.3 := shift(product, n = 2, type = "lead")]


dt <- dt[count > 0 & count.2 > 1 &  count.3 == 1]
dt <- unique(dt, by = "ID")

library(tidyr)
dt.measure <- separate_rows(dt, product.3, sep = ",")
dt.measure <- separate_rows(dt.measure, stock, sep = ",")
dt.measure <- separate_rows(dt.measure, product, sep = ",")

dt.measure[, measure.1 := (product.3 == product.2 & product.3 != stock)]
dt.measure[, measure.2 := (product.3 != product.2 & product.3 != stock)]
res <- dt.measure[, 
  .(
    measure.1 = max(ifelse(measure.1, product.3, NA_character_), na.rm = TRUE), 
    measure.2 = max(ifelse(measure.2, product.3, NA_character_), na.rm = TRUE)
  ),
  ID
]

dt <- merge(dt, res, by = "ID")
dt[, .(ID, measure.1, measure.2)]
# ID measure.1 measure.2
# 1:  1         C         E
# 2:  2      <NA>      <NA>
# 3:  3         D      <NA>
```

Comment: This approach works well for the mock data. But in the real data (500,000+ rows), the product and stock columns are filled with hundreds of items. As a result, the `dt` gets extremely large when we `separate_rows` and my local machine (128GB) runs out of memory. Is there an alternative for `separate_rows`? Perhaps a `regex` solution?

Comment: Well, there are few things that you can do: 1. partition the data and solve problem in chunks (aka make it small) 2. put this data into a database like BigQuery (aka delegate) and use SQL. 3. Check some other packages, e.g. answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34712949/split-column-in-data-table-to-multiple-rows

Comment: Also see this for D3 method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773770/split-comma-separated-strings-in-a-column-into-separate-rows

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the criteria for efficient is, but here's an approach using `embed` and `tidyverse` style. It filters down so you are working with less and less.

Loading up the data and packages (note later on `setdiff` and `intersect` are from `dplry`)

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                  seqs = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,1,2,3,4),
                  count = c(2,1,3,1,1,2,3,1,2,1,3,1,4,1),
                  product = c("A", "B", "C", "A,C,E", "A,B", 
                              "A,B,C", "D", "A", "B", "A", "A", 
                              "A,B,C", "D", "D"),
                  stock = c("A", "A,B", "A,B,C", "A,B,C,E", "A,B,C,E", 
                            "A,B,C,E", "A,B,C,D,E", "A", "A,B", "A,B", "A", 
                            "A,B,C", "A,B,C,D", "A,B,C,D"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Define a helper function to evaluate condition 1

```
meetsCond1 <- function(rseg) { 

  seg <- rev(rseg)

  all(seg[1] > 0, seg[2] > 1, seg[3] == 1)

}
```

The `embed` function warps a time series into a matrix where essentially each row is a window of the length of interest. Using `apply`, you filter down to which rows start relevant sequences.

```
cond1Match<- embed(df1$count, 3) %>%
  apply(1, meetsCond1) %>%
  which()
```

You can translate that back to final products, the previous products, and stock rows of interest to determine the measures by adding offsets. Split them into a list of individual components.

```
finalProds <- df1$product[cond1Match + 2] %>%
  strsplit(",")
prevProds <- df1$product[cond1Match + 1] %>%
  strsplit(",")
initialStock <- df1$stock[cond1Match] %>%
  strsplit(",")
```

For both measures, neither of them can be in the stock.

```
notStock <- map2(finalProds, initialStock, ~.x[!(.x %in% .y)])
```

Then generate your data.frame by retrieving the seqs and ID values of the window. The measures then are just the `intersect` and `setdiff` of the final products with those in the previous rows.

```
data.frame(ID = df1$ID[cond1Match],
           seq1 = df1$seqs[cond1Match], 
           seq2 = df1$seqs[cond1Match + 1],
           seq3 = df1$seqs[cond1Match + 2],
           measure1 = imap_chr(notStock, 
                               ~intersect(.x, prevProds[[.y]]) %>%
                               {if(length(.) == 0) "" else paste(., sep = ",")}

           ),
           measure2 = imap_chr(notStock, 
                               ~setdiff(.x, prevProds[[.y]]) %>%
                               {if(length(.) == 0) "" else paste(., sep = ",")}

           ),
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE
) %>%
  slice(match(unique(ID), ID))
```

which yields the desired output, which seems to limit at most one line per ID. In the original post, you specify you want all reported. Removing the `slice` call would then instead yield

```
#>   ID seq1 seq2 seq3 measure1 measure2
#> 1  1    2    3    4        C        E
#> 2  1    6    7    1                  
#> 3  2    1    2    3                  
#> 4  2    3    1    2                 C
#> 5  3    2    3    4        D
```

If you're looking to really squeeze efficiency, you might be able to gain some by placing the definitions of `finalProds`, `prevProds`, and `initialStock` instead of assigning them to variables first. I would imagine unless your set of matches is really large, it would be negligible.

Answer (score 1):

A rolling window approach using `data.table` with base R code in `j`:

```
library(data.table)
cols <- c("product", "stock")
setDT(df2)[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) strsplit(as.character(x), split=",")), .SDcols=cols]

ans <- df2[, 
    transpose(lapply(1L:(.N-2L), function(k) {
        if(count[k]>0 && count[k+1L]>1 && count[k+2L]==1) {
            m1 <- setdiff(intersect(product[[k+2L]], product[[k+1L]]), stock[[k]])
            m2 <- setdiff(setdiff(product[[k+2L]], product[[k+1L]]), stock[[k]])
            c(seq1=seqs[k], seq2=seqs[k+1L], seq3=seqs[k+2L],
                measure1=if(length(m1) > 0) paste(m1, collapse=",") else "",
                measure2=if(length(m2) > 0) paste(m2, collapse=",") else "")
        }
    }), ignore.empty=TRUE),
    ID]
setnames(ans, names(ans)[-1L], c(paste0("seq", 1:3), paste0("measure", 1:2)))
ans
```

output:

```
   ID seq1 seq2 seq3 measure1 measure2
1:  1    2    3    4        C        E
2:  2    1    2    3                  
3:  3    2    3    4        D
```

Comment: This is interesting. Is the rolling window efficient? That is, does it scale well to data with 500.000+ rows?

Comment: I think rolling window is required for your problem. There might be more efficient method than this. You might want to try on your actual dataset.