# R - Regex matching on elements in character string

Tags: r, regex

I want to know if any elements in character string occur in other character string.

My data contains of millions of rows and is structures as the the following mock data:

```
dt <- data.table(product = c("A", "B", "C", "A,C,E", "A,B", "A,B,C", "D", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A,B,C", "D", "D"),
              stock = c("A", "A,B", "A,B,C", "A,B,C,E", "A,B,C,E", "A,B,C,E", "A,B,C,D,E", "A", "A,B", "A,B", "A", "A,B,C", "A,B,C,D", "A,B,C,D"), stringsAsFactors = F)


dt[, product.2 := shift(product, type = "lead")]
dt[, product.3 := shift(product, n = 2, type = "lead")]

> dt
product     stock product.2 product.3
 1:       A         A         B         C
 2:       B       A,B         C     A,C,E
 3:       C     A,B,C     A,C,E       A,B
 4:   A,C,E   A,B,C,E       A,B     A,B,C
 5:     A,B   A,B,C,E     A,B,C         D
 6:   A,B,C   A,B,C,E         D         A
 7:       D A,B,C,D,E         A         B
 8:       A         A         B         A
 9:       B       A,B         A         A
10:       A       A,B         A     A,B,C
11:       A         A     A,B,C         D
12:   A,B,C     A,B,C         D         D
13:       D   A,B,C,D         D      <NA>
14:       D   A,B,C,D      <NA>      <NA>
```

From this data I would like to know the following:

1. If any element (separated by `comma`) in `product.3` occurs in `product.2`
2. If any element (separated by `comma`) in `product.3` does not occur in `stock`.
3. Do all elements (separated by `comma`) in `product.3` occur in `stock`?

The expected outcome is something like this:

```
> dt
product     stock product.2 product.3 outcome1 outcome2 outcome3
 1:       A         A         B         C    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE
 2:       B       A,B         C     A,C,E     TRUE     TRUE    FALSE
 3:       C     A,B,C     A,C,E       A,B     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE
 4:   A,C,E   A,B,C,E       A,B     A,B,C     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE
 5:     A,B   A,B,C,E     A,B,C         D    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE
 6:   A,B,C   A,B,C,E         D         A    FALSE     TRUE     TRUE
 7:       D A,B,C,D,E         A         B    FALSE     TRUE     TRUE
 8:       A         A         B         A    FALSE     TRUE     TRUE
 9:       B       A,B         A         A     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE
10:       A       A,B         A     A,B,C     TRUE     TRUE    FALSE
11:       A         A     A,B,C         D    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE
12:   A,B,C     A,B,C         D         D     TRUE    FALSE    FALSE
13:       D   A,B,C,D         D      <NA>    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE
14:       D   A,B,C,D      <NA>      <NA>    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE
```

This question is part of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57529311/r-building-new-variables-from-sequenced-data) question on Stackoverflow.

**EDIT 08/20/2019**: Included a third expected outcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
```

According to `?str_detect`

> Vectorised over string and pattern. Equivalent to grepl(pattern, x). See str_which() for an equivalent to grep(pattern, x).

So, one option is to replace the `,` with `|` (or matches) and directly compare the corresponding elements of 'product.2' with 'product.3' similarly with 'stock' comparison on 'product.3'.  Then, replace the `NA` elements with `FALSE` with `set`

```
dt[, outcome1 := str_detect(product.2, str_replace_all(product.3, ",", "|"))]
dt[, outcome2 := str_detect(stock, str_replace_all(product.3, ",", "|"))]
for(j in names(dt)[5:6]) set(dt, i = which(is.na(dt[[j]])), j = j, value = FALSE)
dt
#    product     stock product.2 product.3 outcome1 outcome2
# 1:       A         A         B         C    FALSE    FALSE
# 2:       B       A,B         C     A,C,E     TRUE     TRUE
# 3:       C     A,B,C     A,C,E       A,B     TRUE     TRUE
# 4:   A,C,E   A,B,C,E       A,B     A,B,C     TRUE     TRUE
# 5:     A,B   A,B,C,E     A,B,C         D    FALSE    FALSE
# 6:   A,B,C   A,B,C,E         D         A    FALSE     TRUE
# 7:       D A,B,C,D,E         A         B    FALSE     TRUE
# 8:       A         A         B         A    FALSE     TRUE
# 9:       B       A,B         A         A     TRUE     TRUE
#10:       A       A,B         A     A,B,C     TRUE     TRUE
#11:       A         A     A,B,C         D    FALSE    FALSE
#12:   A,B,C     A,B,C         D         D     TRUE    FALSE
#13:       D   A,B,C,D         D      <NA>    FALSE    FALSE
#14:       D   A,B,C,D      <NA>      <NA>    FALSE    FALSE
```

---

The first two lines of code can be simplified as @d.b mentioned

```
dt[, paste0("outcome", 1:2) := lapply(.SD, str_detect, 
 pattern = str_replace_all(product.3, ",", "|")), .SDcols = c("product.2", "stock")]
```

#### Update

With the update in OP's question

```
dt[, paste0("outcome", 1:2) := lapply(.SD, function(x) 
     str_detect(product.3, str_replace_all(x, ",", "|"))), 
          .SDcols = c('product.2', 'stock')]
dt[, outcome3 :=unlist(Map(function(x, y) {
       x1 <- sort(x[!is.na(x)])
       y1 <- sort(y[!is.na(y)]);
       length(intersect(x1, y1)) == length(x1)},
       str_extract_all(product.3, "[A-Z]"), 
       str_extract_all(stock, "[A-Z]"))) & !is.na(product.3)]

for(j in names(dt)[5:6]) set(dt, i = which(is.na(dt[[j]])), j = j, value = FALSE)
dt
#    product     stock product.2 product.3 outcome1 outcome2 outcome3
# 1:       A         A         B         C    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE
# 2:       B       A,B         C     A,C,E     TRUE     TRUE    FALSE
# 3:       C     A,B,C     A,C,E       A,B     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE
# 4:   A,C,E   A,B,C,E       A,B     A,B,C     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE
# 5:     A,B   A,B,C,E     A,B,C         D    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE
# 6:   A,B,C   A,B,C,E         D         A    FALSE     TRUE     TRUE
# 7:       D A,B,C,D,E         A         B    FALSE     TRUE     TRUE
# 8:       A         A         B         A    FALSE     TRUE     TRUE
# 9:       B       A,B         A         A     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE
#10:       A       A,B         A     A,B,C     TRUE     TRUE    FALSE
#11:       A         A     A,B,C         D    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE
#12:   A,B,C     A,B,C         D         D     TRUE    FALSE    FALSE
#13:       D   A,B,C,D         D      <NA>    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE
#14:       D   A,B,C,D      <NA>      <NA>    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE
```

Comment: Great! Shouldn't the `x` and `pattern` in `str_detect` be switched?

Comment: do you have an idea for the 3 question listed (edited after your original answer)

Comment: Sorry, didn't get a chance to look at it.  I was away

Answer (score 3):

`split` the `product.3` at comma and then use `grepl` to check if it is present in `product.2` or `stock`

```
temp = strsplit(dt$product.3, ",")
sapply(seq_along(temp), function(i){
    any(sapply(temp[[i]], function(x) grepl(x, dt$product.2[i])))
})
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#[12]  TRUE    NA    NA
sapply(seq_along(temp), function(i){
    any(sapply(temp[[i]], function(x) grepl(x, dt$stock[i])))
})
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#[12] FALSE    NA    NA
```

Comment: Does this approach scale well, considering the call to `grepl`